# Error about React Native Splash Screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have installed the React-native-smart-splash-screen from https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen, but after running the react-native run-android command I get the following errors: please see errors in the picture below.

[image]

Please tell me how to resolve the error, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The module has some issues. Did you check the issues section https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen/issues/20 ?
I think this will solve the problem primarily. If the problem persists please check the link below which consists of configured link for splashscreen.
https://github.com/UjjwalNepal/Dental

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because your local system didn't have a particular version which you trying to install,

To resolve this,

- Go to your Android Studio Package manager
- Click on show package details
- If you want 23 version SDK, Install complete 23 and 23 subversions, like if you choose 23 is your main version, you have to install 23.0.0 and as well as its complete subversions like 23.1.1, 23.3.3, etc.

Hope this works for you.

[image]